# htaccess trocar "_" por "-"

Tags: php, htaccess, mvc

Tenho este código que estou utilizando no meu MVC que fiz pra estudos:

```
class Como_Funciona extends Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {

        $data = [
            'title' => SITE_TITLE . ' - ' . SITE_SUBTITLE,
            'brand' => SITE_BRAND,
        ];

        $this->_view->render_template('header', $data);
        $this->_view->render_template('navbar', $data);
        $this->_view->render_template('pages/faq', $data);
        $this->_view->render_template('footer', $data);
    }
}
```

Minha url fica da seguinte forma:

```
http://domain.com/como_funciona
```

Gostaria de deixa-la assim:

```
http://domain.com/como-funciona
```

É possível fazer isto com .htaccess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O htaccess não vai mudar a sua URL direto no browser, ela permanecerá a mesma. Internamente ele irá fazer a conversão dos caracteres de acordo com os seus critérios. Por exemplo:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_(.*)$ $1-$2 [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?router=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Ao passar a URL "minha_url_para_modificar, no PHP quando você fizer a captura, retornará assim:

```
<?php

var_dump($_GET);
```

Saída no browser:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: MAs vou poder passar `-` ao invés de `_` ? esta é minha dúvida.

Comment: Pode sim! é recomendado pelas boas praticas enviar na url com o separador "-" ao inves de "_".

Comment: minha_url_para_modificar é um método correto? Se eu passar na url localhost/teste/minha-url-para-modificar ele encontra o método?